# can"t display data from RestApi

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I was trying to display the response data from Rest Get Api but the data is not displaying and also there is no error.

Please help with this.

**my html code**

```
<div>
  <app-my-page *ngFor="let c of data">{{c}}</app-my-page>
</div>
```

**my component.ts code**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ChartDataSets,
  ChartOptions
} from 'chart.js';
import {
  Color,
  Label
} from 'ng2-charts';
import {
  DataService
} from '../data.service';
import {
  User
} from '../User.module';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-page',
  templateUrl: './my-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-page.component.css']
})
export class MyPageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("here");
    return this.dataService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(data => this.Users$ = data);
  }
}
```

**my user.module.ts**

```
export class User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

**my app.module.ts code**

```
import {
  HttpClientModule
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  DataService
} from './data.service';

imports: [HttpClientModule], **
  my dataservice.ts code **

  import {
    HttpClient
  } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  User
} from './User.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  apiurl = 'http://localhost:8080/test/test';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers() {

    return this._http.get < User[] > (this.apiurl);
  }
}
```

edited: no error in browser console and rest api is having data[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDY7L.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRfnv.png)

Comment: There should be some type of error in the console? Unless your database has no data

Comment: @HenryLy Thanks for going through my post. I have edited my question showing there are no errors and the rest api is having data. Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: there is no `data` varilable in the component class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. it should work.

```
export class MyPageComponent implements OnInit {
          data: any;
          constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
        
          ngOnInit() {
            console.log("here");
            this.getUsersDetails();
          }
    
          getUsersDetails(){
              this.dataService.getUsers()
              .subscribe(result=> { 
                  this.data = result
              }, error => {
                  console.log(error)
              });
          }
        }
```

Comment: i tried your code but its showing multiple pages in my browser

Answer (score 0):

your component class does not have data variable. follow the following pseudo code

```
export class MyPageComponent implements OnInit {

  data: User[]; // this is missing in your class

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("here");
    return this.dataService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(users => {
        this.data = users; // set the value of data like this
    });

  }
}
```

and you are good to go